# GFCI outlet tripping

Tags: electrical

My son has 2 regular outlets the second leads to the first of 4 GFCI outlets in the kitchen. When he uses either regular outlet it trips the GFCI. We changed both outlets although there was no apparent defects or damage. It still trips the GFCI. We then changed the GFCI. Again it trips when either of the two regular outlets are used. He can use the GFCI (the one that trips) with no problems and the three after the one that trips are fine. Which makes me believe the problem lies before the GFCI outlets begin.  It drives me nuts when I can figure things out. Anyhow here's a list of the order of the outlets.

Regular - Regular - GFCI( the one that trips) - Switch for above sink light - GFCI - GFCI

How GFCI is wired below:

Left side one 3 whites
Right side 2 blacks
Bottom ground

---

GFCI outlet wiring drawing ,,,,,,,,,,,

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you saying that a GFCI device is feeding other GFCI devices? That is wrong. One GFCI outlet will protect everything attached to its "Load" terminals (electrically downstream). There is no need to have more than one GFCI on a branch. I know from experience that compact fluorescent lights will "fight" with a GFCI if they are plugged in to it or fed by the Load terminals. Eventually one or both will burn out. You have something wrongly wired. Remove the downstream GFCI devices, and any fluorescent lamps / fixtures and see what happens. Your description of the wiring worries me also.

Comment: It strikes me as odd that's there's 3 white wires, and only 2 black.  How many white wires are attached to the LINE side of the GFCI, and how many are attached to the LOAD side?  I'm guessing there are two whites on the LOAD side, and the rouge white wire is what's  causing the problem.

Comment: If you look at the GFCI on the top there is two white wires and on the bottom there is one white wire Then on the hot side there is one black wire on top and one black wire on the bottom.  After the first GFCI  (the one that trips) there is a switch for the light above the sink and then the other GFCIs.  I'm not sure if the switch has anything to do with how the GFCI is wired.

Comment: @Kenny On the back of the GFCI, the terminals should be labeled LINE and LOAD.  Top and bottom  is not useful, as the device can be installed either way, and the terminals may vary by manufacturer.

Comment: You can't have an odd number of wires, that is just wrong.

Comment: Can you clearly describe all the wiring in that box? A diagram and/or photos would be helpful.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm going to have to text my son to see is he can pull it out and look. He just bought the house and moved in in December.  I thought all those GFCI outlets looked like over kill.

Comment: I drew a picture of the wiring into it tester, I thought it didn't look right no comprende. I never saw a GFCI wired like this. How do I add a picture?

Comment: Edit the question, and you should see a button to add a photo in the editor. Or upload the image to imgur.com, and share a link in a comment.

Comment: Describing it would be as follows: when we pulled out the GFCI it has holes in the back where you stick in the wires then tighten them with the screws. It appears there are two holes per screw. Looking from the front of the GFCI left is for the white wires and right is for the black wires. When we pulled it there were two white wires one in each hole at the top and one in the bottom hole.  Then the one black on top and one on bottom other side. Then of course the ground.

Comment: I don't see the photos button. Maybe because I'm on my phone.

Comment: Sounds to me like there's an extra white (neutral) on the LOAD side neutral terminal.  Current is returning on this wire, and passing through the GFCI.  However, since the current is not flowing (out) through the GFCI, the device is tripping. Figure out what the extra white wire is, and hook it up properly.

Comment: [This post](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/990/33) describes how to add an image from the Android app.

Comment: So one of the white wires should go?

Comment: Probably, or a black (hot) should be added. That "extra" white must be part of a circuit, and should have a black (hot) companion. If you remove the white, it will have to be hooked up somewhere, otherwise something will stop working.

Comment: Maybe for the switch that follows it???  How would I add another black if there is not one to add?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will see what I can do. I maybe be back on in the next couple of days to ask more questions.

Comment: Get some photos, or draw an accurate diagram.  Otherwise we're all just guessing.

Comment: Ok I'll get on tomorrow to add the drawings

Comment: Thanks testor101 when I get on my laptop tomorrow I will get the drawing on there. I will also text my son to see the brand of GFCI.

Comment: @Kenny Thanks, for the drawing. However, to answer this question accurately, we're going to need to know about every wire in the box, not just those attached to the GFCI.

Answer (score 2):

I think Kenny above was right.

From your wire count, on the load side, it looks like one black and one white go off to the properly-working GFCI outlets (which as others have pointed out need not be GFCI since they are downstream of a GFCI) while the "regular" outlets are probably getting a white from the GFCI load side, and a black from somewhere else (line side of the GFCI probably unless someone has accidentally mixed two circuits here).

This should be pretty easy to sort out and clean up, you just have to figure out which cable is the line feed, which goes to to downline kitchen outlets, and which goes to the downline regular outlets.

Comment: +1, "borrowed neutral" = bad practice = problems like this. Rated [C2- potentially dangerous](http://www.electricalsafetyfirst.org.uk/mediafile/100404922/Best-Practice-Guide-4-Issue-4.pdf) in UK EICR.